# @FXML Annotation not working correctly

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I'm currently working on a 'small' project with JavaFX. I used the SceneBuilder to create the first sketch of my GUI. it still needs some adjustment and styling but I wanted to see if it's working so far.

I have 2 hyperlinks on the GUI, if the user clicks one of them the default system-browser should open with a specific URL.

So far I got this:

Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    DataBean dataBean= new DataBean(primaryStage);
    Controller controller = new Controller(dataBean);
    controller.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

DataBean.java:

```
public class DataBean {

private Stage primaryStage;

public DataBean(Stage stage) {

    primaryStage = stage;
}

public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
}
}
```

TestautomatView.java:

```
public class TestautomatView implements Initializable {

@FXML 
private ComboBox<String> environmentCombo;

@FXML 
private Hyperlink crhl;

@FXML
private Hyperlink help;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

}

private Scene scene;
private BorderPane root;

public TestautomatView() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(new URL(TestautomatView.class.getResource("Sample.fxml").toExternalForm()));

    scene = new Scene(root);
}

public void show(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("CrossReport Testautomat");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}


public ComboBox<String> getEnvironmentCombo() {
    return environmentCombo;
}

public Hyperlink getCrhl() {
    return crhl;
}

public Hyperlink getHelp() {
    return help;
}

public Scene getScene() {
    return scene;
}

}
```

In my controller I want to set the ActionHandler to the hyperlinks but it's not working because the getters in my view return null.

```
public class Controller  {

private DataBean dataBean;
private TestautomatView view;

public Controller(DataBean databean) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    this.dataBean = databean;
    this.view = new TestautomatView();

    setActionHandlers();
}

public void show() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    view.show(dataBean.getPrimaryStage());
}

private void setActionHandlers() {
//      setHyperlink(view.getCrhl(), "www.example.com");
//      setHyperlink(view.getHelp(), "www.example2.com");
}

private void setHyperlink(Hyperlink hl, String uri) {
    hl.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            //TODO - Open Default Browser
        }
    });
}

}
```

When I start my application, I can see the GUI but when I want to add the ActionHandlers I get a NullPointerException.

In the ´Sample.fxml´ file the hyperlinks are children of a HBox

```
<Hyperlink fx:id="crhl" text="Report" />
<Hyperlink fx:id="help" text="Help" />
```

But it's not just the hyperlinks even the ComboBox is null when I inspect my app in the debugger.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `new URL(TestautomatView.class.getResource("Sample.fxml").toExternalForm())` why??? The url won't work better, if you convert it to `String` and back...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in another answer, the issue is that you create an instance of `TestautomatView` "by hand". The default behavior of the `FXMLLoader` is to create an instance of the controller class specified in the FXML file, and use that instance as the controller. Consequently, you have two instances of `TestautomatView`: the one you created (and have a reference to), and the one that was created by the `FXMLLoader`. It is the second one that has the `@FXML`-annotated fields initialized.

You can change this default behavior by creating an `FXMLLoader` instance, and setting the controller on it directly. E.g. consider doing:

```
public class TestautomatView implements Initializable {

    @FXML 
    private ComboBox<String> environmentCombo;

    @FXML 
    private Hyperlink crhl;

    @FXML
    private Hyperlink help;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    private Scene scene;
    private BorderPane root;

    public TestautomatView() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(TestautomatView.class.getResource("Sample.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        root = loader.load();

        scene = new Scene(root);
    }

    // etc...

}
```

Since you are directly setting the controller, you need to **remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the `Sample.fxml` file** for this to work.

You may also be interested in [this pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components), which is quite similar (though not exactly the same) as what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are creating your controller manually by using `new TestautomatView()`. It must be created by FXMLLoader for annotations to work. You must also set `fx:controller` attribute in `Sample.fxml` to your controller (`TestautomatView`) fully qualified class name.

Example code:

```
FXMLLoader fl = new FXMLLoader(new URL(TestautomatView.class.getResource("Sample.fxml").toExternalForm()));
root = fl.load();
TestautomatView controller = fl.getController();
```

PS: You should rename your `TestautomatView` to `TestautomatController`. FXML file is your "view".